# Check if a hostname is valid or not in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

i want to check with a simple batch script, if a Computer is pingable or not.
In some case, i misstype and the hostname is incorrect, but as a feedback comes "Successful".

```
@echo off
REM stor.bat:
ping -n 1 %1 | find "TTL=" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
        echo Reachable
        explorer.exe \\%1\c$\   
    
) else (
        echo Not reachable
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your command is based on find "TTL=" which works for ip4 numbers so this should work

```
@echo off
REM stor.bat:
ping -n 1 %1 | find "TTL="
if %errorlevel%==0 (echo Reachable & explorer.exe \\%1\c$\) else (echo Not reachable & pause)
```

so

```
stor 127.0.0.1
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reachable
```

but ping is not ideal with names see this response where success is not shown

```
stor advent
Not reachable
```

however `ping -n 1 advent` returns no hint of "TTL"

```
Pinging ADVENT [fe80::6467:ace9:6aef:cb1a%10] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::6467:ace9:6aef:cb1a%10: time=1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::6467:ace9:6aef:cb1a%10:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
```

one method is "Find" something in response like "round trip"

```
@echo off
REM stor.bat:
ping -n 1 %1 | find "round trip"
if %errorlevel%==0 (echo Reachable & explorer.exe \\%1\c$\) else (echo Not reachable & pause)
```

**[Edit]** as reminded by @Stephen we can use your first method by adding -4 to force The TTL=

```
@echo off
REM stor.bat:
ping -4 -n 1 %1 | find "TTL="
if %errorlevel%==0 (echo Reachable & explorer.exe \\%1\c$\) else (echo Not reachable & pause)
```

Comment: force `ping` to use IP4: `ping -4` or `ping ... | findstr /c:"(0%%"` goes both with IP4 or IP6 (only one `%` directly on the command line)

Answer (score 0):

This `batch-file` will ping the host to identify if it is available. This uses PowerShell Core. If you are only using Windows PowerShell, change `pwsh.exe` to `powershell.exe`.

Remember that some hosts may have ICMP (ping) disabled.

Also, if you mistype a hostname that is online (host02 instead of host01), it will also return as successful.

```
SET "THEHOST=%1"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('pwsh.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "if (Test-Connection -TargetName %THEHOST% -Count 1 -Quiet) { 1 } else { 0 }"') DO (
    SET /A "ISCONNECTED=%%A"
)
IF %ISCONNECTED% EQU 1 (
    ECHO The %THEHOST% is connected
) ELSE (
    ECHO The %THEHOST% is NOT connected
)
```